# MKLocalSearch to table view in Swift

Tags: uitableview, mapkit, core-location, swift3, xcode8

I am looking at searching a local area for "Grocery Stores", using core location and MKLocalSearch.

I think I got the "local search" down, but I am not sure what to do with the results.  I am running xcode8 with swift3.

I am looking to fill this table with the Store Name, Address, and to pass along GPS Coordinates a new view controller for another "setup" process.

I would love a youtube link (or instruction) to properly setup the tableview and then the code to populate the information from MKLocalSearch.

Thanks!

```
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(){
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.025, longitudeDelta: 0.025)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!, span: span)

    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Grocery"

    request.region = region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.start { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in
        print(localSearchResponse)
        //Code needed here to fill table view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the local search response you can extract the necessary data you require like coordinates, title of the store, and address as follows:

First initialise an empty array which will be used to populate your tableView:

```
var searchResults: [MKMapItem]()
```

Next populate this list with your search response and update the tableView with the new data:

```
search.start { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in
    searchResults = localSearchResponse.mapItems
    tableView.reloadData() // update the tableView data source
}
```

Then update your tableView with appropriate formatting of results:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let searchResult = searchResults[indexPath.row]
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    cell.textLabel?.text = searchResult.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = searchResult.subtitle
    return cell
}
```

Finally if you want to pass the coordinate data to another viewController, you could do this by passing the whole array or more than likely you will want to do this upon selecting the cell and passing the mapItem associated with the cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let searchResult = searchResults[indexPath.row]
    let groceryViewController = // initialise the new viewController
    groceryViewController.coordinate = searchResult.placemark.coordinate

    // push the new viewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(groceryViewController, animated: true)
}
```